# Accent characters like à,É are not working with google chrome + silverlight 4

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, silverlight-4.0, telerik

Accent characters like à,É are not working with Google chrome & Firefox in Silverlight 4 application.

It is working in IE.

If I set Silverlight object's windowless=false then it is working but at the moment the I have used `RadHtmlPlaceholder` control of telerik in one page and its not working.

What is other options for displaying HTML page in Silverlight application?

Answer (score -1):

What character-set are you using for the control? Try specifying one that supports all the characters you want.

Comment: where and how i can specify character-set for a control? and how can i find available character-sets?

Comment: I dont know much about Silverlight, but after going through its documentation, changing the object's property to `windowless=false` was the only way of achieving accent chars. Though, I failed to find much about `RadHtmlPlaceholder`. Guess, you'll have to do without this control.

Comment: @HiteshPatel: [You might find this helpful](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/editor/rad-editor-accentuated-characters-and-html-entities.aspx)

Comment: @Ecko Thanks for your comments but the post is regarding the telerik RadEditor Control for the asp.net. and i need to display html page in my silverligth application.